# Permission Denied for mkdir on Mac

Tags: macos

Ok I don't know any linux command and just trying to follow the instructions in here:
http://www.bigspaceship.com/2011/02/installing-mongodb-on-mac/

So I opened the terminal and typed

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

but it said Permission Denied.

What should I do?

Answer (score 23):

Try this command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

`sudo` executes the command with higher privileges, and will ask for your password before it lets the command be executed.

Comment: Ok cool, now if I type "db" in Spotlight, it will find it...but how about command line? how do I navigate to this folder in Terminal?  in DOS forexample we could say CD\DB

Comment: It is still cd in linux, so cd /data/db  
To show the contents of the directory you want to use ls instead of dir, so ls /data/db

Comment: what if we don't want to use sudo? Will there be permission errors in the future with mongodb?

Answer (score 12):

You do not have permissions to create the directory. As you are trying to run this as your own user, and as I suspect `/data/db` is hardcoded somewhere, you should be able to do

```
sudo install -m 0755 -o $USER -d /data/db
```

This will use super user privileges (`sudo`) to create two directories (`/data`, and `/data/db`). `/data/db` would be owned by the user specified by `-o` - you (`$USER`) and will have `0755` permissions - owner with full permissions, and everyone read-only access. If the parent directories are missing, they will be created and owned by root (cannot find docs about this, but experiments confirm it).

I suggest you do it this way because the rest of the instructions you will still do as your own user.

Comment: explanation of the 0755 bit http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-permissions-chmod-of-a-file

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
mkdir -p data/db
```

No slash before the `data`

Comment: This worded for me. It creates /data/db under current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X Catalina and higher `/data` became a reserved path  https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/working-apfs-volume-groups

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on mac os x. I solved this by executing `sudo -p mkdir data`, `cd data` and after this `sudo -p mkdir db`. Good luck.